# mock a private method which doesn't return anything using Junit

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am writing a test case in `Junit` for function which is `public[firstFunction]` and its invoking another function which is private.

```
public firstFunction(Object1 object1 , Object2 object2){
       secondFunction(object1,object2)
}
private secondFunction(Object1 object1 , Object2 object2){
       ....
}
```

I am trying to write a test case using but unable to find solution3

Comment: Why do you need/want to mock? You wouldn't be testing your class if you mock it.

Comment: It would help if you would provide more concrete details. What do those two functions actually look like? and what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.